# Announce game played on facebook for ios

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I have seen on my facebook feed announcements saying that so-an-so played this game.

[image]

And I'm wondering, is this just a regular post to someones wall that the app makes when the user plays this game? Or is it some other sort of announcement when a user registers their game with facebook by logging in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/ Step 5 is an option or you get publish_actions permission from app users and then you can publish to their walls through the app.